# More efficient way to INSERT data from Sybase into Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm using ColdFusion to copy data from a Sybase database into Oracle 11g. Both databases have the exact same tables and columns. I only know to use the following method and wanted to know if there is a more efficient method.

I am currently doing a `select * from table_A` in Sybase. Then looping through the query result and inserting the data into my Oracle database:

```
 <cfloop query="GetTableA" datasource="SybaseDB">
    <cfquery name="InsertToOracle" datasource="OracleDB">
     INSERT INTO (column list...)
     Values (values from GetTableA)
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Doing it like what I'm doing right now is acceptable for a small amount of data. However, performance starts to degrade when looping over more than 2000 records.

Comment: I suggest that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

If both databases are located on the same data center, or close enough, one good option is to use a DB Link. This article talks about accessing a Sybase database from an Oracle database:
[How to query Sybase database from Oracle database via db link](https://myoraclebase.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/setup-heterogeneous-services/)

Once the connection is established, is just a matter of:

```
INSERT INTO [oracle_table] ...
SELECT ... FROM [sybase_table]
```